# regarding webservices

Tags: web-services

I've started learning about webservices recently. Have few question about that:

1. For webservice, is it always necessary that source should provide wsdl or any other way possible to consume it without needing wsdl?
2. Till a while ago, I was doing  server side XMLhttp post in classic ASP to do modifications in external application & to push data in my application from external application. I'm confused - is that  very different from webservice or can be called a sort of webservice(ofcourse without based on SOAP). Any major difference or it is just protocol difference bw webservice and server side XMLhttp post?
3. Web services can be made asynchronous?(Something like AJAX call through javascript)
4. Are there any different types of webservices ? (for e.g is there difference bw, webservice providing stock quotes and webservice provided by google)

Answer (score 0):

> 1.For webservice, is it always necessary that source should provide wsdl or any other way possible to consume it without needing wsdl?

`WSDL` is a document that publishes an interface. As long as a client complies to the inteface, it is guaranteed to be able to "talk" to the web service. Having said that `WSDL` is a formal way for a specification when there are many stakeholders. You can proceed without one, as long as you somehow know what the web service expects. Just wrap the application data in a `SOAP` envelope and send it to the web service. As long as you send what the web service expects (in the `SOAP` envelope or the application data) and in the way they are expected e.g. transport `HTTP` etc. it does not matter for the `WS` if you have used a `WSDL` or not.

> 2.Till a while ago, I was doing server side XMLhttp post in classic ASP to do modifications in external application & to push data in my
>   application from external application. I'm confused - is that very
>   different from webservice or can be called a sort of
>   webservice(ofcourse without based on SOAP). Any major difference or it
>   is just protocol difference bw webservice and server side XMLhttp
>   post?

In very simple terms web service is `XML` over some application protocol (usually `HTTP`). Could be `SOAP` based or `REST`. To understand more on this you should read about `Service Oriented Applications`

> 3.Web services can be made asynchronous?(Something like AJAX call through javascript)

They *could* but it is more complicated than that.

> 4.Are there any different types of webservices ? (for e.g is there difference bw, webservice providing stock quotes and webservice
>   provided by google)

Not sure what you ask here. Each web service offers something.

Comment: Thanks you for clearing doubts.. After this. I'asked a question to other user. What is different b/w REST AND server side XMLhttp post in classic ASP.. not able to find much difference so far what I read!

Answer (score 0):

I will try to be very simple here:

> The W3C defines a "Web service" as "a software system designed to
>   support interoperable machine-to-machine interaction over a network".

That means first requisite for any software to be web-service is that it should not depend upon platform or software i.e a web service made on java stack can be consumed by client in .net stack on windows or java stack on android.

- If your server side implementation XMLhttp post suffice this ,its a
  web service.

> Types of Web services

Actually, there is no overall and clear categorization on types of web services. But two most popular are :

1. **SOAP based web services**. :It  use XML messages that follow the Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP) standard, an XML language defining a message architecture and message formats(WSDL).
2. **REST based web services**. With evolution of WEb 2.0 emphasis has been moving away from SOAP based services towards representational state transfer (REST) based communications.[3] REST services do not require XML, SOAP, or WSDL service-API definitions.[Read here to get a easy explanation of REST](http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife)

> Need of WSDL to consume SOAP web services?

To consume a SOAP service we only require SOAP endpoint and XML message format. WSDL is a pre-requisite for automatic client side code generation through Java and .NET SOAP frameworks.

> Asynchronous web services

Making web services asynchronous is possible.But complexity depends upon frameworks used, for example AXIS2 in JAVA has easy implementation of this.

Comment: Thanks! ..for clearing my points..just small thing..I was reading about REST. Though, I think,understanding completely will take some time..but it just look like..similar to server side XMLHttp post in classic ASP.Is there any major difference b/w two?

Comment: Yes, indeed they are different. Rather than technology, REST is about architectural style. Read the link i provided to get a fair idea. POST request in a REST is used for creating a new entity.